# Save buffer from winsock recv hook (PChar to AnsiString)

Tags: delphi

I know this is kind of silly question but sometimes I get really stuck in this Ansi/Unicode thing and I try every damn conversion (PChar/AnsiString/PAnsiChar....) and still unreadable buffer. And this is my case here. I'm hooking "recv" function, and I just want to save the buffer content into a file, but I get only chinese/unreadable characters into that file. My callback function is:

```
function Interceptrecv(s: TSocket;
            Buffer: Pointer;
            BuffLength: integer;
            Flags: integer): Integer; stdcall;
  var
    MyBuff: PChar;
    pFileHandle, dWrite: cardinal;
    sText: string;
  begin
    Result:= recvNext(s, Buffer, BuffLength, Flags);
    GetMem(MyBuff,sizeof(Buffer));
    ZeroMemory(MyBuff, sizeof(Buffer));
    CopyMemory(MyBuff,Buffer,sizeof(Buffer)-1);
    SetLength(sText, SizeOf(MyBuff));
    CopyMemory(@sText[1], MyBuff, SizeOf(MyBuff));
    pFileHandle := CreateFile(PChar('C:\' + 'log.txt'),GENERIC_WRITE,0,nil,OPEN_ALWAYS , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
    if pFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      SetFilePointer(pFileHandle,0,nil, FILE_END);
      Windows.WriteFile(pFileHandle,sText,SizeOf(sText),dWrite,nil);
      CloseHandle(pFileHandle);
    end;
  end;
```

How to make this buffer legible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code fails is because you are completely misusing `SizeOf()`.  You need to use the return value of `recvNext()` instead:

```
function Interceptrecv(s: TSocket;
            Buffer: Pointer;
            BuffLength: integer;
            Flags: integer): Integer; stdcall;
  var
    MyBuff: PAnsiChar;
    pFileHandle: THandle;
    dWrite: DWORD;
    sText: AnsiString;
  begin
    Result := recvNext(s, Buffer, BuffLength, Flags);
    if Result <= 0 then Exit;
    GetMem(MyBuff, Result);
    try
      ZeroMemory(MyBuff, Result);
      CopyMemory(MyBuff, Buffer, Result);
      SetLength(sText, Result);
      CopyMemory(PAnsiChar(sText), MyBuff, Result);
      pFileHandle := CreateFile(PChar('C:\log.txt'), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
      if pFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      begin
        SetFilePointer(pFileHandle, 0, nil, FILE_END);
        Windows.WriteFile(pFileHandle, PAnsiChar(sText), Result, dWrite, nil);
        CloseHandle(pFileHandle);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(MyBuff);
    end;
  end;
```

If your intent is to save the received data as-is, then you have made the code way more complicated than it needs to be.  You are making not one but two copies of the received data in memory, which is wasteful and unnecessary.  You can simplify the code to the following:

```
function Interceptrecv(s: TSocket;
            Buffer: Pointer;
            BuffLength: integer;
            Flags: integer): Integer; stdcall;
  var
    pFileHandle: THandle;
    dWrite: DWORD;
  begin
    Result := recvNext(s, Buffer, BuffLength, Flags);
    if Result <= 0 then Exit;
    pFileHandle := CreateFile('C:\log.txt', FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if pFileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    begin
      Windows.WriteFile(pFileHandle, Buffer^, Result, dWrite, nil);
      CloseHandle(pFileHandle);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: In the log file I get 90% unreadable content and things like:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 13:02:27 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
P3P: policyref="http://www.hotwords.com.br/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="ALL DSP COR CUR OUR IND PUR"
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Injecting into browser. I believe there's HTML codes too, you sure I shouldn't treat the buffer before save it?

Comment: Since you are hooking `recv()` directly, you are seeing *raw* data, in this case for an HTTP session. HTTP is a mix of text and binary data. You will have to parse the HTTP data to ignore what you don't want, and keep what you do want. You have to take into account that the HTTP data will span across multiple `recv()` calls, and across multiple socket connections, so keep track of what you are parsing per socket. That is going to be a lot of work. Hooking `recv()` might not be the best solution. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just learning more about hooks and right now decided to control the flux of html code that reach google chrome. But I got a very curious behavior because some websites I get the HTML source clearly in the log, but for other ones, just doesnt appear in the log. Always the same sites appear, and others don't. Looks like chrome uses recv sometimes and others don't. But this is senseless for me.

Comment: Some sites may already be in the browser's cache so it does not have to retrieve them from the server. Or mabe the sites are compressed and your log stops displaying after a null bytes is encountered.

Comment: Hummm... This thing about null bytes makes sense. I tried cleaning the history so the cache is not the problem. But the null bytes, can be... If you can, try to give me a tip about how to fix this and remove the null bytes to save complete log. I'll do a research too. Thank's.

Comment: I tried: `Result := recvNext(s, Buffer, BuffLength, Flags);
    if Result <= 0 then Exit;
    GetMem(MyBuff, Result);
    try
      ZeroMemory(MyBuff, Result);
      CopyMemory(MyBuff, Buffer, Result);
      SetLength(MyString, Result);
      CopyMemory(PAnsiChar(MyString), MyBuff, Result);
      i:= 1;
      while i < Length(MyString) do
        if MyString[i] = #0 then
          Delete(MyString, i, 1)
        else
         inc(i);
      if POS('<html>', MyString) > 0 then
      begin
        MessageBox(0, 'Foundd!', 'HOOK', MB_OK);
     end;`

Comment: Your while loop needs to use `<=` instead of `<`, since `MyString` is 1-indexed. Personally, I would not suggest using `AnsiString` at all, just remove the nulls from `MyBuff` instead. But then you are altering the meaning of the raw data, if you need to process it in its original format. Better to just encode non-ascii bytes saving the data to the log, but don't alter them in memory.

Comment: You are also not taking into account that raw data can span multiple reads, so there is no guarantee that `Pos('<html>', MyString)` will ever work. You MUST save the raw data off to the side somewhere so that you can recombine split data back together, then scan that buffer, not the raw data being received. Think about it. You might receive `'<ht'` one time, then receive `'ml>'` the next time, so you would have to save `'<ht'` somewhere so you can then append `'ml>'` to it the next time, thus allowing you to then search for `'<html>'`. That is just the nature of TCP, you have to deal with it.